# Is there a conditional to distinguish NeoVim and Vim within vimrc?

Tags: vimrc, neovim

I want one vimrc to work with both Vim and NeoVim. The vimrc of Vim seems to work well with NeoVim. But not the other way around, given that there are many special new settings in NeoVim, e.g., terminal mode.

I want not to manage two individual vimrc files needed to be sync'd periodically.

Is there a way within .vimrc to let some statements work with NeoVim alone?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [NeoVim's Github issue tracker](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/1931), you can use `has('nvim')`:

```
if has('nvim')
   "something for neovim
endif
```

Comment: Or `!has` for plain vim (for those who aren't fluent in VimL)